# BasicCard shared type returns open_url_action: the protocol must be http or https in the Google Assistant Console

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

When my Dialogflow webhook returns a BasicCard in the response to the Google Assistant console, I receive the error:

> MalformedResponse
>   expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[1](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/Message#Button_1).basic_card.buttons[0].open_url_action:
>   the protocol must be http or https.

[The docs say that this type should look like](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/Message#Button_1):

```
"basicCard": {
    "buttons": [
        {
            "title": "button text",
            "openUriAction": {
                'uri': "https://www.google.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "formattedText": "Some text",
    "image": {
        "url": "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png",
        "accessibilityText": "Accessibility text describing the image"
    },
    "title": "Card Title"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in the Dialogflow docs.

The proper webhook response should be:

```
"basicCard": {
    "buttons": [
        {
            "title": "button text",
            "openUrlAction": {  <--- URL, not URI
                'url': "https://www.google.com" <-- URL, not URI
            }
        }
    ],
    "formattedText": "Some text",
    "image": {
        "url": "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png",
        "accessibilityText": "Accessibility text describing the image"
    },
    "title": "Card Title"
}
```